# Which library to use for OneDrive access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make requests to OneDrive but as I am reading documentation I am not sure which oauth2 library to use. [Here](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) is link to recommended oauth2 library where I should choose from supported [third party providers](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/docs/providers/thirdparty.md) . I am not sure whether to choose **Microsoft** or  **Auzre Active Directory**

Answer (score 0):

I would say "it depends".

For OneDrive for Business - the Office 365 version, your users are in Azure Active Directory.

The home version of OneDrive just requires a Microsoft Account. Then you should use that authentication directory.

Comment: Well, I want to be able to upload files to user OneDrive from my page. I guess they can have regular or business accounts.

Comment: There is no single solution for this. If you integrate with the Azure AD version 2.0 endpoint which should give you access to both OD for Business and Personal, your enterprise customers may have some limits that won't work.  But check out https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview for information and samples.